# Local DNS server is not resolving names when machine is connected to VPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, dns, openvpn

I'm trying to set up a small VPN Network using OpenVPN which will allow me to connect to my workstation in the office from home.

I've already set up OpenVPN server, generated keys and client config files.
Everything works I can connect to my work machine in the office from home via RDP but there is one issue - DNS names for local resources cannot be resolved when work PC is connected to my VPN:

```
C:\Users\user>nslookup jira.corporate_domain.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.54.11

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out

C:\Users\user>nslookup google.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.54.11

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out

C:\Users\user>nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4008:808::200e
          216.58.219.142
```

I've add our local DNS server to client config file and also added a static route for that, it doesn't work. Here are the current settings on the client:

Client PC OS: **Windows 10**

**client_config.ovpn**:

```
client
nobind
dev tun
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server

remote vpn.dns_name_of_my_server.ru 443 tcp
http-proxy proxy.corporate_dns_name.com 3129
dhcp-option DNS 192.168.54.11 
route 192.168.54.11 255.255.255.255 192.168.37.1
route 192.168.70.11 255.255.255.255 192.168.37.1
```

**`ipconfig /all`** on the client:

```
C:\Users\user>ipconfig /all
Windows IP Configuration
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : S0003445
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : ad.corporate_domain.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : ad.corporate_domain.com
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-B6-98-50-62
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cd6:8fec:5f45:9f4f%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.255.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 30 сентября 2016 г. 17:23:51
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 30 сентября 2017 г. 17:23:50
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.255.5
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 369164214
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-ED-10-9F-10-C3-7B-4C-A0-FA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.54.11
                                       8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ad.corporate_domain.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 10-C3-7B-4C-A0-FA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1c57:9c8c:64b2:1aeb%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.37.106(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 29 сентября 2016 г. 11:04:00
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 7 октября 2016 г. 11:03:57
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.37.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.70.21
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 51430267
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-ED-10-9F-10-C3-7B-4C-A0-FA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.70.11
                                       192.168.54.11
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-34-4C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8cd8:5f1d:f24f:fc95%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 201850919
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-ED-10-9F-10-C3-7B-4C-A0-FA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-F8-A8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e0b9:a45e:e853:1456%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.99.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 285736999
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-ED-10-9F-10-C3-7B-4C-A0-FA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
Tunnel adapter isatap.{E1337BD8-BE7B-4699-B5B6-6404A1995408}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.ad.sperasoft.com:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ad.sperasoft.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.{B6985062-CC79-4BE2-9963-92484A01C1D6}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Tunnel adapter isatap.{9CB069EA-424F-4D8A-AE63-43372ED9F0BF}:
   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Local DNS server is available via **`ping`**:

```
C:\Users\user>ping 192.168.54.11

Pinging 192.168.54.11 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.54.11: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=126
Reply from 192.168.54.11: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=126
Reply from 192.168.54.11: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=126
Reply from 192.168.54.11: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=126

Ping statistics for 192.168.54.11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 40ms, Maximum = 42ms, Average = 41ms
```

Static route to it is also working fine judging by **`tracert`**:

```
C:\Users\user>tracert 192.168.54.11

Tracing route to 192.168.54.11 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.37.1
  2    40 ms    39 ms    39 ms  192.168.50.2
  3    44 ms    40 ms    40 ms  192.168.54.11

Trace complete.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: block-outside-dns option on client https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=21633

Comment: @maudam, I've added this parameter to client config while I was connected through RDP and it seems like it broke the config since reconnect was not successful and I lost connection to that machine.
Not sure what went wrong, I can check only on Monday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I wasn't able to solve an initial issue with DNS resolution but after some thinking I realized that VPN for the mentioned task (an ability to connect to working station from the Internet) is an overkill.

It's far easier to configure reverse ssh port forwarding for 3389 (RDP) and bypass corporate firewall by using existing HTTP proxy server (ssh daemon on VPS server should listen on 443 port for this to work)

Answer (score 1):

You may have got it working by pushing the domain DNS suffix to your client and moving the TAP adapter to the top of the binding order (lowest metric).  Were you able to successfully ping the FQDN of the domain hosts you were trying to reach?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond.
I didn't mange to get it working (probably due to lack of my knowledge). But I guess this is a good time to try again.
Give me some time to rethink everything and create initial setup.